# Replace values with NAs based on a column condition

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, replace, na

I have a dataframe with different columns, one of which tells me if data in other columns can be "trusted" or not, containing a "yes" or a no" (column name: `inside_calibration_range`). What I would like to do is simply to replace the values in the whole row with `NA` every time I have a "no" in the `inside_calibration_range` column.

I gave it a look to `dplyr::na_if` and `replace_with_na_all()` functions, but (I may be wrong) it seems they do not accept conditions, but they replace specific values in the whole dataframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why not just drop those rows? How would all NA values be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `cyl` equal to 6 cannot be trusted in `mtcars`, we can `mutate` `across` `everything` to NA for that condition:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
as_tibble(mtcars %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~replace(., cyl == 6 , NA))))

# A tibble: 32 × 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  NA      NA   NA     NA NA    NA     NA      NA    NA    NA    NA
 2  NA      NA   NA     NA NA    NA     NA      NA    NA    NA    NA
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  NA      NA   NA     NA NA    NA     NA      NA    NA    NA    NA
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  NA      NA   NA     NA NA    NA     NA      NA    NA    NA    NA
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  NA      NA   NA     NA NA    NA     NA      NA    NA    NA    NA
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Select only some columns instead of all:

```
as_tibble(mtcars %>% mutate(across(c(mpg, disp), ~replace(., cyl == 6 , NA))))

# A tibble: 32 × 11
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  NA       6   NA    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
 2  NA       6   NA    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 4  NA       6   NA    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
 6  NA       6   NA    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
10  NA       6   NA    123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, 
however I think that this command as the consequence to replace all the rows with the range of values within the "conditional" column. You can see that in your example as well, where number of cylinders other than 6 are assigned to all the columns of the dataframe.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. All values are NA when a particular variable, e.g. `cyl` had a particular value, e.g. `6`. All other variables and values are preserved.

Comment: Thanks Marco!
One connected question....would it be possible to put the NAs in some selected columns instead in all the columns?

Comment: Hi, this was working, but going through the script again is not working anymore.

I have no errors, simply running the code below it creates the dataframe "predsNA", but with no NAs (it is basically a copy of original "preds" dataset)

`predsNA <- as_tibble(preds %>% mutate(across(c(15:57), ~replace(., inside_calibration_range == "no" , NA))))`

It does not change anything if I provide columns names.

Thanks to anybody who can help.

Comment: That'd be guessing. Can you please provide your data with `dput()`? Make sure what is in `preds`. Number of columns 15 to 57? Name of variable `inside_calibration_range`? Value of variable `no`?